# system command ends function before end in R

Tags: r, system, rna-seq

I have created a `salmonify` function in R which takes all the fastq files in a folder and then runs the `salmon quant` function in command line one after another using the `system` function. However, after the `system` function completes the list successfully, the rest of the `salmonify` function will not run. ie. it does not print the statement, and if I try nesting the `salmonify` function in another function (to run it for multiple study folders), it stops at the same place.

I am using a linux ubuntu 18.04. The salmon function is the latest (1.1.0), and R is version is 3.6.

The code is:

```
salmonify_single = function(hardrive, study, index){
  salmon_file = "salmon quant -i "
  code1= " -l A -r fastq_files/"
  code3 = " -o Salmon/quant/"
  name = paste0(hardrive, "/", study, "_data/fastq_files")
  L = list.files(name)

  O = gsub(x = L, pattern = "_1.fastq", replacement = "")
  code4 = O[! duplicated(O)]

  lst = as.list(L)

  lst3 = list()

  for (i in seq_along(lst)) {
    x = lst[[i]]
    lst3[i] = paste0(salmon_file, index, code1, x[1], code3, code4[i])
  }

  for (i in lst3) {
    print(i)
  }

  fold_name = paste0(hardrive, "/", study, "_data")
  setwd(fold_name)

  for (i in lst3) {
    system(i)
  }
  print(paste0("Completed salmonify for ", study))
}
```

The output for printing the list that will run from

```
for (i in lst3) {
    print(i)
  }
```

is :

```
> salmonify_paired("DATA/RNAseq_Analysis3", 
+                  "dikovskaya", "salmon_index_k31")
[1] "salmon quant -i salmon_index_k31 -l A -1 fastq_files/SRR2095296_1.fastq -2 fastq_files/SRR2095296_2.fastq -o Salmon/quant/SRR2095296"
[1] "salmon quant -i salmon_index_k31 -l A -1 fastq_files/SRR2095297_1.fastq -2 fastq_files/SRR2095297_2.fastq -o Salmon/quant/SRR2095297"
[1] "salmon quant -i salmon_index_k31 -l A -1 fastq_files/SRR2095298_1.fastq -2 fastq_files/SRR2095298_2.fastq -o Salmon/quant/SRR2095298"
[1] "salmon quant -i salmon_index_k31 -l A -1 fastq_files/SRR2095299_1.fastq -2 fastq_files/SRR2095299_2.fastq -o Salmon/quant/SRR2095299"
[1] "salmon quant -i salmon_index_k31 -l A -1 fastq_files/SRR2095300_1.fastq -2 fastq_files/SRR2095300_2.fastq -o Salmon/quant/SRR2095300"
[1] "salmon quant -i salmon_index_k31 -l A -1 fastq_files/SRR2095301_1.fastq -2 fastq_files/SRR2095301_2.fastq -o Salmon/quant/SRR2095301"
```

Then the salmon function begins, and then I can't get it to print `Completed salmonify for...`. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Best,

James

Comment: Have you verified that the commands that you attempt to run actually run and complete as expected? Do you know how much time each of those commands is supposed to take to complete? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question to answer your comment. Yes, it appears to produce all the quant folders successfully.

Comment: `system2` is preferred to `system`.

Comment: It didn't like system2  Warning messages:
1: In system2(i) : error in running command